# How to make all CButton controls with the same ID in a series of dialogs invisible in VC6?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-c++-6

I have a

```
std::map< long, CDialog* > m_maplongDialog;
```

It is filled with code similar to:

```
m_maplongDialog.insert(std::make_pair(nIndex, new CSomeDlg));
m_maplongDialog.insert(std::make_pair(nIndex, new CSomeOtherDlg));
...
```

btw: nIndex is an index from a CListCtrl where I am making a table of names of these dialogs to select.

Later my user selects one of these dialogs in a list and I show it like this:

```
m_maplongDialog[izbraniSifrant]->DoModal()
```

All this works!
But now I have an additional request:
In all of these dialogs there are OK and CANCEL buttons among other stuff. I have to make the OK one invisible before I do the DoModal thingy.

Hopefully I am understood in this writing. Its kinda hard to explain.
So any ideas would be appreciated greatly.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to override `CDialog::OnInitDialog` for respective dialogs, and call:

```
GetDlgItem(IDOK)->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);
```

before returning from overridden `OnInitDialog`

Comment: The problem is I am using those same dialogs somewhere else in a complete form, that is with the IDOK shown

Comment: Your comment is not clear. You want to selectively hide and show buttons depending on some condition? Or you have OK buttons on some dialogs and not on other dialogs? Or you think this will hide OK buttons in all dialogs??

Comment: I have a few different dialogs that are dynamically created. I use those same dialogs in other parts of the application. So I have to make one of the buttons of these dialogs invisible in this part of the application, but the other, older part, must stay the same. All I am doing in my case is calling those dialogs one by one and I am showing them without the OK button. Also I am very great full for your help.

Comment: Use a boolean flag in constructor of your dialog class, or have some method that would set this flag. Depending on this flag, you can hide the button.